# Hashmap Object Parsing String into long or int

Tags: android, android-studio, hashmap

I am trying to populate a ListView with an Object. I am getting an error

"java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long"

The data that I am pulling out of my web database is a String and its trying to place it into a long. I understand why I get the error and where I'm getting the error but I don't know how to fix it.

Here is my object:

```
public static Person createFromGenericMap(Map<String, Object> object) {

        Person p = new Person();

        p.personID = (long) object.get("personID");
        p.phoneNumber = (int) object.get("phone");
        return p;
    }
```

and here is where I think the problem is:

```
ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();

            for (Map<String, Object> personObject : objects) {
                Person p = Person.createFromGenericMap(personObject);
                people.add(p);
            }
```

Update: Its pulling all the information from my web database correctly but the issue is still in the long to string.

LOGS:

05-09 22:53:18.098 2147-2147/com.f0xcr4f7.intelwatch D/Kumulos Client: [{lastName=Johnson, middleName=Steven, firstName=Drake, dob=153446400, address=2312 W Lakeview, Waco, TX 72015, phone=2147483647, dl=765432345, ss=435097656, personID=1, timeCreated=2016-03-30 16:41:00, timeUpdated=2016-04-10 02:40:48, race=w, sex=m, age=43, 05-09 22:53:18.102 2147-2147/com.f0xcr4f7.intelwatch E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

```
                                                                   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long java.lang.Long.longValue()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Does the *personID* have any non-numeric characters?

Comment: Would also help if you can put some Logs to check the value that you're getting. To verify if you're note getting any non-numeric characters.

Comment: I updated it with the logs. Its pulling the data but having issues with the conversion from long to string.

Comment: The error is different now. Previously it was a cast exception, now it's an NPE.. and just to clarify with your comment *Its pulling the data but having issues with the conversion from **long to string***, you want the long value as String?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the value you get for key *personID* doesn't have any non-numeric characters, I think your casting is correct, but for some reason it doesn't seem to work. Can you try this:

```
p.personID = Long.getLong(object.get("personID").toString());
```

You can also have a second parameter for [Long.getLong()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Long.html#getLong(java.lang.String)) as a default value if ever.

Cheers! :)

Comment: This seems to work as its no longer showing an error:                  p.personID = Long.valueOf(object.get("personID").toString());

Comment: I see. You are now receiving an NPE. If you put logs, what value do you get for `object.get("personID").toString()` ?

Comment: Webservice is saying success but its crashing as my view is wrong lol. Seems to be working.

Comment: Sorry mate. Got confused there. Is the code now working? Were you able to fix it? :)

Comment: I believe so. I wish my adapter view was working so that I can give a 100% answer. After I fix the adapter ill come back here and give a direct yes or no. thx for all the help!

Comment: p.personID = Long.valueOf(object.get("personID").toString()); Works! Wanted to give you credit with the assist.

Comment: That's great. Cheers! :D

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cast String to Long, use this:

`Long.valueOf(String str)`

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Long.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)

EDIT: for a primitive long, use : `Long.valueOf(str).longValue()`